# Application started, loaded, initialized event in Swing JAVA

Tags: java, swing, events, initialization, windowlistener

The question is theoretical, so no code I have. I wonder, what if I want to do something in the very beginning when my Swing application started. I haven't found any methods like: **started()**, **loaded()**, **initialized()** for Swing app. Are there any? Is **"WindowListener"** the only way?
Imagine, that I would like to smth like (p-code):

```
    public class SwingFC extends javax.swing.JFrame {

SwingFC() {   ...some code when the instance constructed...    }

public void started(){ 
System.out.println("hello, I've just started - " + this.getName());
  }
 }
```

So, how can I catch all these lifecycles?

Comment: what about constructor

Comment: Why not the [`windowOpened`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowOpened%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) method of a [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)? And what exactly do you mean by "started"? - When the frame is set to visible, when all work inside the constructor is done, etc.?

Comment: why would you need another one windowlistner does the job?

Comment: @Priyamal Because I interpreted "started" as "first time window is set to visible", which doesn't necessarily have to be inside the constructor.

Comment: I just want to know are there methods like those or not. It is easier, I think, than use the  **WindowListener**

Comment: @SergeyLotvin You can view a full method summary [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), at least I can't see any method that would be equivalent to the `windowOpened` method by default, except you'd for example override `setVisible`. I think the best way would just be to make a custom `JFrame` class, which e.g. has the method `onStart` that gets called when `windowOpened` of the `WindowListener` is called.

Comment: OK! Thanks to All!